# Build sucess - not able to run tests through maven for appium

Tags: maven, appium

Running a maven project for appium, build is success but it is not running any tests, while running through suite it works fine with maven it only builds but does not run the tests, have checked my `JAVA_HOME` path, `M2_HOME` and `MAVEN_HOME` path in `TestNG` scope is given as test have checked my project structure also but NOT ABLE TO RUN TESTS...below is the project structure, console details and `pom.xml` using eclipse....please help me out on this. thanks

CONSOLE:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MavenAndroid 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.testng:testng:jar:5.14.3 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.testng:testng:jar:5.14.4 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.testng:testng:jar:5.14.5 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.66 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for velocity:velocity-dep:jar:1.5-beta2 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ MavenAndroid ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Rathan\workspace\Testing\MavenAndroid\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ MavenAndroid ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ MavenAndroid ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Rathan\workspace\Testing\MavenAndroid\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ MavenAndroid ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to C:\Users\Rathan\workspace\Testing\MavenAndroid\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) @ MavenAndroid ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.072 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-10T12:23:03+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/278M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.andriod</groupId>
  <artifactId>MavenAndroid</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>MavenAndroid</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>



    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
            <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-dep</artifactId>
            <version>1.5-beta2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>





        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Includes the Sauce JUnit helper libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.saucelabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>sauce_junit</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
             <scope>test</scope>
            <version>6.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suitexmlfiles>
                        <suitexmlfile>testng.xml</suitexmlfile>
                    </suitexmlfiles>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                            <value>false</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <workingDirectory>target/</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>java-net</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>snapshot</id>
            <name>snapshot repository</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>saucelabs-repository</id>
            <url>https://repository-saucelabs.forge.cloudbees.com/release</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

further im running through maven test directly does it have any impact should be follow Maven run as-> maven clean->build and then test or directly run as maven test is correct.

Comment: What is command You are calling from Jenkins?

Comment: @Kovacic  thanks for ur reply...i have not yet integrated with jenkins once maven works fine will integrate it..please correct me if im incorrect

Comment: OK, not with Jenkins but what is maven command that You try to ran, to get tests up and running?

Comment: Eclipse-pom.xml->right click->Run as->maven test...it will build and then run the testsuite from tstng

Comment: try running with "mvn test" commands,here are examples:
running single test:

1.mvn -Dtest=TestClassName#general_Header_checkElements_Logo test

2.running all tests (from class):
mvn -Dtest=TestClassName test

3.running all tests from multiple classes (from testsuite xml file):
mvn -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=testsuiteTesng.xml test

Comment: and if this doesn't work, than You have issues with dependencies, than try instead of "LATEST" in your pom with actual version values

Comment: thanks...i have replaced with the exact versions in pom still the same error i have integrated with Jenkins with freestyle project excluding maven build is success full but tests does not run